# How do i determine the primary (android device) account data eg gmail?

Tags: android, gmail

I can get the device (owner's)phone via

```
TelephonyManager tm = 
          (TelephonyManager)ctx.getSystemService(ctx.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
phone = tm.getLine1Number();
```

But i am not sure how to determine the gmail or other account belonging to this user(device)

How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) (available in Eclair and higher) to access this information. You can find an example of how to use this interface in the [ContactManager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html) sample application bundled with the SDK.

Comment: That example does not tell you who the device owner is or does it?